# async forEach next method not waiting

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, async.js

My below code is firing the async next callback before my Photo `find()` *promise* is done. 
I thought `async.forEach` didn't fire until `next` was called.

I'm trying to get my photo[0] to come out in the same order as the category:item.strId is passed in. Right now its not working that way and is returning random orders. Is there a way to wait for the promise before the next loop in forEach happens. I thought that's what the callback of async was for. Or am I misunderstanding it.

```
exports.fetchHomeCollection = (req, res, next)=>{
  const collection = [];

  Category.find({count : { $gt : 0}}).then(categories =>{
    async.forEach(categories, function(item, next){
      console.log("item.strId = ", item.strId);
        Photo.find({isDefault:true, category:item.strId}).then((photo)=>{
          console.log("photo = ", photo);
          collection.push(photo[0]);
          next();
        });
    },
    function(err){
      if(err) console.log("fetchHomeCollection async forEach error");
      res.send(collection);
    });
  })

}
```

I'm using global.Promise as my `mongoose.promise`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix Promises with async.js. They don't work well together.

```
exports.fetchHomeCollection = (req, res, next)=>{
    async.waterfall([
        function (cb) {
            Category.find({ count: { $gt : 0 }}, cb);
        },
        function (categories, cb) {
            async.map(categories, function (category, next) {
                Photo.findOne({ isDefault:true, category: category.strId }, next);
            }, cb);
        }
    ],
    function (err, photos) {
        if (err) 
            console.log("fetchHomeCollection async forEach error");
        res.send(photos);
    });
};
```